# Where can I see the what() message from an unhandled std::exception in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to see the explanatory string from an unhandled exception? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express and can't seem to find a way to see it.

When I run the following code:

```
#include <stdexcept>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    throw std::runtime_error("warp core breach");
    return 0;
}
```

all I get in the output window is this:

```
First-chance exception at 0x7652C41F in vstest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x0015F6A4.
Unhandled exception at at 0x7652C41F in vstest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x0015F6A4.
```

I would have expected the "warp core breach" message to be printed there. I have all options under Debugging->Output Window->General Output Settings set to On.

Comment: @Nick Certainly I could catch it, but I just want to know how I can see the message in the case when it's not caught. Surely there must be a way to do so when debugging?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You'll get a window when the exception is thrown with the option to break/continue/ignore. Copy and paste the hex address this dialog reports, then click the `break` button. Now in a watch window, enter something like: `(std::runtime_error*)(0x002cfbc8)` into a cell in the first column.

[image: watch window]

Comment: isn't there something to do this automatically?