# Can I view an unhandled exception in the Visual Studio 2017 Debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

A library I am using (zmq) throws an exception. The debugger breaks and informs me.

**How, if possible, can I see this exception. Specifically the what() message?
 Without having to place try/catch around it and printing to the output stream.**

- It does not appear in the Autos or Locals watch lists. I have searched the stack frames around the point at which it occured.
- Adding $exception to a manual watch list simply returns a value of "identifier $exception is undefined"
- Using memory explorer to interrogate the exception's location does not show anything useful.

I have read this can be done when using the CLR - can I do it in regular C++?

Comment: Could you get the Exception messages in the output window now if you turn on the exception messages under Debugging option now?

Answer (score 5):

Referencing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498348/where-can-i-see-the-what-message-from-an-unhandled-stdexception-in-visual-st#):

You'll get a window when the exception is thrown with the option to break/continue/ignore. Copy and paste the hex address this dialog reports, then click the break button. Now in a watch window, enter something like:

```
(std::exception*)0xXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Doing this (manually) every time is very annoying. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: I don't know this for now. Maybe add some catch/conversion in the source code?

Answer (score 2):

(1) Please check that whether the Exception messages was enabled in the output window under Tools->Options->Debugging->Output window.
[image]

(2)If it still no exception messages, one possible reason is that zmq really doesn't support the Exception throw feature of VS. Of course, you could write a general app like C# or VC++ which can prove it. If other apps have no this issue, we would think about the specific zmq.

Comment: Yes, the dialog matches your screenshot, but still nothing in the output window if it breaks into the debugger, and only "Exception thrown at 0x76C0A882 in XXXXX.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::exception at memory location 0x00DEF2D8." if I turn off breaking on that exception.

Comment: @sebf, Do you enable all exception options under Exception Settings window? The VS2017 has a new feature which could show the Exception: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/31/using-the-new-exception-helper-in-visual-studio-15-preview/. If it really doesn't could show the messages in the output window, you could use this feature, check the result in your side.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, this isn't currently possible. I've added a User Voice suggestion [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/31281400-allow-a-thrown-c-exception-to-be-inspected) but I'm not sure when, if ever, Microsoft will implement this feature.

For now, what you can do is take the **Type** and **Location** of the exception (from the message '*Exception thrown at **Address** in **Module**: Microsoft C++ exception: **Type** at memory location **Location**.*', and then add to the Watch window the expression '**(Type*)Location**'. If **Type** is some internal exception type that you don't have access to, then you can hope it derives from *std::exception* and cast to that instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft threw away user voices.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Identify the exception (it would be logged in the output window in VS)
Step 2. Put an exception breakpoint with the exception you saw from the output.

If this is ZeroMQ, I'd wager you're Sending 2 requests on a REQ socket without waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 0):

your output window

> (View/Output or click CTRL + ALT + O)

is where you should see the message, but you may need to check the exceptions option:

[image]

[Look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx) for more detail

Comment: @Idgorman, I have Exception Messages enabled, and I also have all relevant exceptions enabled in the Exceptions Window, but my Output Window does not display anything when one occurs: http://pasteboard.co/EqHRV6gp.png