# Exception messages hidden by visual studio/debugger breaking on the wrong line

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Visual studio is hiding my exception messages. Take the following code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

void exceptional_method(){
    throw std::runtime_error("Hello from exceptional_method!");
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    exceptional_method();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Visual studio gives me some vague addresses:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x76A9DDC2 in ExceptionTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x006FFD34.
```

Whereas linux mint gives me the following output on the terminal:

```
Hello world!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Hello from exceptional_method!
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've googled a bunch, messed around with the settings in Visual studio, but cannot figure this out. My current workaround is writing the exception message to console before throwing so that I can at least catch the message so I know which exception was thrown.

```
inline void throw_exception(string& message)
{
    cout << message << endl;
    throw runtime_error(message);
}
```

This is not ideal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit:
Getting the debugger to break on the actual exception instead of a few lines ahead was the problem, causing me to investigate the wrong code.
The following solution is what I was looking for.

```
#ifndef DEBUG_ASSERT_H
#define DEBUG_ASSERT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

inline void log_failed_assert(const string message, const string expression, const string file, const long line) {
    cout << "Assert failed." << endl;
    cout << "Expression: "   << expression  << endl;
    cout << "Message   : "   << message     << endl;
    cout << "File      : "   << file        << endl;
    cout << "Line      : "   << line        << endl;
}

inline void windows_break()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    __debugbreak();
#endif
}

//do {
//} while (0)

#ifdef _DEBUG
#ifdef _WIN32
#define DEBUG_ASSERT(expr, s) do{\
    if(!(expr)){\
        log_failed_assert(s, #expr, __FILE__, __LINE__);\
        __debugbreak();\
    }\
    } while(0)
#else
#define DEBUG_ASSERT(expr, s) do{\
    if(!(expr)){\
        log_failed_assert(s, #expr, __FILE__, __LINE__);\
    }\
    } while(0)
#endif
#else
#define DEBUG_ASSERT(expr, s)
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: Put a try catch block around the code in main and output the exception message from the catch.  Linux Mint is just being helpful, there is no requirement for the tool-chain to include the code to output uncaught exception messages.

Comment: @RichardCritten Tried this and you are right. What if I don't want to catch the exception? I use exceptions in another codebase for debugging. I want to break where it goes wrong. Does this mean I can't use exceptions for this purpose?

Comment: @fstam You can catch the exception and then rethrow it. Just add `throw;` to the end of your catch block.

Comment: To break when exception is thrown in VS you can set up Exception Filters. Note that throwing (uncaught) exceptions does not require cleanup either so you application may not exit properly.

Comment: I'm looking at assert() from assert.h now. Seems to do exactly what I want.

Comment: Note that [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) is a *macro* and it's not enabled in typical release builds. Anyway, you should never let internal exceptions or assertions reach the end-users; Catch them, log them, and then tell the user something nice and sugarcoated, and exit.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm aware of this, as I said before I just want to break while debugging. This is not supposed to end up in a release build. A macro is perfect for this because you can define an empty version of the macro in release builds.

Comment: Well if you want to break while debugging, that will happen automatically when throwing an exception. The VS debugger should break directly to the location where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude while it does break, it breaks on the wrong line. This caused the initial problem. see: https://i.imgur.com/WgYEMHg.png

Comment: Well unless you have two consecutive lines both with `throw` statements in them, then it shouldn't be that hard to figure out the exception is the one from the previous line. :)

Comment: Maybe for you, I spent a whole day pulling my hair out. That should be unnecessary. Then again I'm a C# dev and not a C++ dev.

Comment: @RichardCritten Please add you comment as answer so I can mark this question answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I see the what() message from an unhandled std::exception in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498348/where-can-i-see-the-what-message-from-an-unhandled-stdexception-in-visual-st)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions are there to be catched. If you dont catch it your program will terminate. If this is what you want, there are easier ways to terminate. If you catch the exception in `main` you can use the message to eg print it:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
void exceptional_method(){
    throw std::runtime_error("Hello from exceptional_method!");
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    try {
        exceptional_method();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what(); 
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

As RichardCritten pointed out, it is mint being nice to you rather than visual studio "hiding" the message, as there is no requirement to print the message when your program terminates.

Comment: Since RichardCritten didn't add his own answer, Ill mark this one.

Comment: that's really annoying. I have to disable the catch statement to see the exception's message..... is there no way to instpect the exception directly when the debugger breaks on its throw?

Comment: @user1050755 you dont need to "disable the catch". `e.what()` is the message of the exception. The posted code should display the message on the screen when it is catched

Comment: that message doesn't include the source code location...

Comment: @user1050755 then include it the message... something like `throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Hello from exceptional_method!") + std::to_string(__LINE__) + std::to_string(__FILE__));`

Comment: it's a 3rd party lib that throws them. The catch also prevents the debugger from stopping at the appropriate location. isn't there a MSVC extension to dump std::exception messages when the debugger intercepts them?

Comment: @user1050755 you seem to have an issue that is different from the question here. Then you should ask a new question