# printing cv::Mat to std::cout with operator<< memory exception error for multidimensional array

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm just starting to learn openCV, but I'm already struggling with the basics.
Running MSVS2019 16.3.5 with opencv 4.1.2

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    cv::Mat kernel2d{ 2, 3, CV_32F, cv::Scalar(0) };
    std::cout << kernel2d << '\n';
}
```

Gives a nice:

```
[0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0]
```

But I live in a 3D world... so:

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int const size3d[]{ 2, 3, 4 };
    cv::Mat kernel3d{ 3, size3d, CV_32F, cv::Scalar(0) };
    std::cout << kernel3d << '\n';
}
```

which leads to

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB75299129 in OpenCVSandbox.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location
>   0x000000A2A24FEE00

edit: ah, I saw this message

> OpenCV(4.1.2) Error: Assertion failed (m.dims <= 2) in
>   cv::FormattedImpl::FormattedImpl, file
>   C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\out.cpp,
>   line 87

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [check the details of the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13499024/1460794) and then add those to the question.

Comment: @wally thanks. The link tells me about hitting a `break` button... but where's that? I've tried to google it, but it's not clear. I found an error message in the output window I overlooked... I'm getting a bad feeling about this... as if in OpenCv 4.1.2 outputting 3D `Mat` is not supported... even though multi-dimensional `Mat` has been in openCV since at least 3.0...

Comment: It looks like a pause button. Or press ctl+alt+break.

Comment: @wally still not that simple... but I found my answer with your tips... close voted my own question as duplicate. Indeed openCV is not supporting output of N-dimensional arrays for N>2... Sometimes open-source stuff is really frustrating...

Comment: I wouldn't throw OpenCV away because stream output of multi-dim. matrices doesn't match your expectations. I strongly believe it has its strengths for what it is supposed to. ;-) To add a custom formatting output for (multi-dim.) matrices shouldn't be that hard (if you really need it).

Comment: @Scheff yeah... that's what it comes down to... I'm glad they don't build open-source cars, where it turns out you have to make the brake system yourself (or so).